# Log in fails on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, login-screen

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on hp-elitedesk.

Once in a while, when I log in, instead of going to the desktop screen, it comes back to the same log in screen.

I am very afraid of someday, it will get stuck in the loop and won't be able to retract my data. Can anyone suggest why this is happening, and is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: You can always get your data booting from a LiveUSB.

Comment: Probably you are writing a wrong password (or username). Check the logfiles in /var/log for registretons around the time of login failure.

Comment: If it's once in a while, it might well be that you did not login. An issue with the keyboard might make enter the wrong password. Check if all the keys behave well in normal use. There is a file `.xsession-errors` in your home folder, that might have information on the issue.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I don't see `.xsession-errors`

Comment: Even if the login manager ever failed completely, it wouldn’t completely remove access to your data- it’s likely the issue is related to the display manager/DE and not the system itself. If you are using some type of LDAP to log in to a corporate network, I’ve had that cause login issues also. No matter what, you’ll still have the ability to drop into a root shell and back things up independent of the graphical environment you use.

Comment: I guess, it seems that I have to cope with it than try enormous amount of time to try to track the cause. Thank you!